# What is kthrotld?

Tags: kernel, process, ps

I'm struggling to find any documentation online relating to process number 54.

```
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   11:24   0:00 [kthrotld]
root     11385  0.0  0.0  12944   992 pts/0    S+   11:30   0:00 grep --color=auto kthrotld
```

I think it may be a kernel thread. Can anyone advise the purpose of this [kthrotld] and the documentation online where I can look this up?

Comment: https://tiro.org.uk/posts/mystery-processes/

Comment: It helps to search with the exact spelling (`kthrotld` instead of `kthrotled` in the title)

Comment: a hack to your server see this article [https://www.srv24x7.com/kthrotlds-cve-2019-10149-exim/](https://www.srv24x7.com/kthrotlds-cve-2019-10149-exim/)

Answer (score 2):

Reading @muru's recommendation https://tiro.org.uk/posts/mystery-processes/

It's a kernel thread which:

> is 'controlling IO bandwidth on a request queue' by throttling requests.